# Сокращение кода открытия файлов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сократить код:

```
@my_bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def get_text(message):
    str_1 = 'привет'
    txt_1 = random.choice(list(open('answer1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    str_2 = 'как дела'
    txt_2 = random.choice(list(open('answer2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    str_3 = 'что делаешь'
    txt_3 = random.choice(list(open('answer3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    str_4 = 'расскажи интересный факт'
    txt_4 = random.choice(list(open('answer4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    str_5 = 'не устал работать'
    txt_5 = random.choice(list(open('answer5.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    text_1 = set(str_1.split())
    text_2 = set(str_2.split())
    text_3 = set(str_3.split())
    text_4 = set(str_4.split())
    text_5 = set(str_5.split())
    inp = set(set(message.text.lower().split()))
    if inp & text_1:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
    elif inp & text_2:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_2)
    elif inp & text_3:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_3)
    elif inp & text_4:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_4)
    elif inp & text_5:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_5)
```

У меня получилось так:

```
@my_bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def get_text(message):

    txt_1 = random.choice(list(open('answer1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
    f1 = set('привет')
    f2 = set('как дела')
    f3 = set('что делаешь')
    f4 = set('расскажи интересный факт')
    f5 = set('не устал работать')
    inp = set(set(message.text.lower()))
    if inp & f1:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
    elif inp & f2:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
    elif inp & f3:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
    elif inp & f4:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
    elif inp & f5:
        my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, txt_1)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно сократить код открытия файлов?

```
txt_1 = random.choice(list(open('answer1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
txt_2 = random.choice(list(open('answer2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
txt_3 = random.choice(list(open('answer3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
txt_4 = random.choice(list(open('answer4.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
txt_5 = random.choice(list(open('answer5.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')))
```

Comment: Что по Вашему мнению должно вернуть выражение `set('что делаешь')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы не сократили, а вот что сделали:

```
str_3 = 'что делаешь'
text_3 = set(str_3.split()) # {'что', 'делаешь'}
f3 = set('что делаешь') # {'е', ' ', 'ч', 'о', 'а', 'ь', 'ш', 'т', 'л', 'д'}
```

Чтобы сократить нужно писать так:

```
f3 = set('что делаешь'.split())
```

2. Чтобы сократить обращения к файлам - вынесите это в отдельную функцию:

```
def choice_from_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        choice = random.choice(list(file))
    return choice

txt_1 = choice_from_file('answer1.txt')
```

---

`set(set(...))` - бесполезная конструкция. одного `set` всегда достаточно.